# What are some other use cases for pallet indices?

Tags: account, indexing

The default implementation is to use a `u32` as `AccountIndex`. This means that only 2^32 claims can be made. Besides reserving an integer, can we use `String` as `AccountIndex` thereby referencing an account with a name instead of a number?

Edit #1: Can we use it in place of regular addresses to send/receive funds?

Comment: What do pallet indices in the title have to do with `AccountIndex` in the question?  
PS: For custom address lookup you can use the [Account lookup](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4339/tlookup-as-staticlookupsource-vs-taccountid).

Comment: Ah, you probably meant `pallet-indices` and not the plural of a pallet index. I see 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The default implementation is to use a u32 as AccountIndex. This means that only 2^32 claims can be made.

Yes. This is an assumption that often occurs within Substrate. `usize` is truncated into `u32` in multiple places. You can change it in your runtime though.

> Besides reserving an integer, can we use String as AccountIndex thereby referencing an account with a name instead of a number?
> […] Can we use it in place of regular addresses to send/receive funds?

There exists the `Lookup` and `StaticLookup` trait which can translate a generic value into an `AccountId`. You probably want something like this:

```rust
fn transfer(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    receiver: String,
)
```

but that has the downside of being limited to `String`. So now you would need different functions depending on the receiver type; not good.
Instead Substrate uses `Lookup` in many places, so that it becomes:

```rust
fn transfer(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    receiver: <<T as frame_system::Config>::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source,
)
{
    let target = T::Lookup::lookup(receiver)?;
```

You can now translate all kinds of types by implementing that trait.
There is a good example in the Darwinia repo where Ethereum addresses are translated to Substrate: [here](https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-common/blob/0448b1abb0ccba5b964bdd57ebf185d33de56235/node/primitives/src/lib.rs#L181-L201).

Comment: They are translating any address to an `AccountId` which I believe is the equivalent of the `AccountId` one would define in `runtime/src/lib.rs` yes?

Comment: Yes. (minimal comment length)